# installing requirements of pyspark job before spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, virtualenv, dependency-management

I want to run a Python application on a Spark cluster, sending it there via `spark-submit`. The application has several dependencies, such as `pandas`, `numpy`, `scikit-learn`. What is a clean way to ensure that the dependencies are installed before submitting the job?

As I have used virtualenv for development, a `requirements.txt` can easily be generated.

Answer (score -2):

You have to run the job in cluster mode. Assuming you are using Yarn as the scheduler.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster my_script.py --py-files my_dependency.zip
```

Also try the following

```
from sklearn import grid_search, datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

Regarding pandas, If you have the exact Data structure you can call `toPandas()`

numpy is generally integrated into a lot of pyspark calls but not sure of this though.

Comment: s`park-submit`!

Comment: Do I need to manually package all dependencies (numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pandas...) into `my_dependency.zip`? Could I instead pass a list of requirements and rely on `pip`?